# update document using a unique filed with findOneAndUpdate is thorwing exception

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean

I am new to node.js and mean.

I have nearly 20 fields to update in a document.

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.model('UserSchema');
```

I am passing these 20 fields in the `request body` and updating the `UserSchema` model object.

```
var newUser =new  UserSchema(req.body);
```

Actually i am not passing `_id` from my request body but when i saw my `newUser._id` it is filled up with some id, so it resulting in an error called

```
exception: After applying the update to the document {_id: ObjectId('560e506ad4369d2a02a6ad6d') , ...}, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('560e65f395857e210313d3a7')



  UserSchema.findOneAndUpdate({ userName: newUser.userName }, newUser, { new: true }, function (err, newuser) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json({ message: err });
      }
      return res.status(200).json({ result: newUser });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating new record set by following statement,

```
 var newUser =new  UserSchema(req.body);
```

Above statement will match all provided fields by `req.body` with registered schema for `UserSchema` Model and will generate new `ObjectId` for it. So `newUser` variable have `_id` field and when you try update existing record with `newUser`, it causes error as you are trying to change immutable `_id` field.

Instead you can re-write whole as following,

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.model('UserSchema');
var newUser = req.body;

UserSchema.findOneAndUpdate({ userName: newUser.userName }, newUser, { new: true }, function (err, newuser) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json({ message: err });
      }
      return res.status(200).json({ result: newUser });
    });
```

And if provided record does not exists then `findOneAndUpdate` will insert new as you provided `new: true` flag.